# Bad request error when enabling SSL and http redirection

Tags: http, ssl, apache2, lets-encrypt, bitnami

I configured and enabled SSL and everything worked fine. But after enabling redirection from http to https I get the following error when opening the website:

```
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You’re speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
```

I noticed this only happens when visiting the site by typing `mywebsite.com` on the browser search bar and when I visit it, the url shows up like this: `http://mywebsite.com:443/`

If I remove the :443 part it works properly and redirects to https.

How can I make it so it doesn't go to the wrong url when visiting from the browser? At the moment I've disabled the redirection to avoid my clients trying to come back to the site and getting that error.

Update:

Here's the config I used:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Found here: https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/apps/wordpress/administration/force-https-apache/

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. It seems that you are redirecting all the HTTP requests to the port 80 to http://yourdomain:443. Please ensure that you are redirecting to https://yourdomain (notice the s in https. You don't need to set the port). In case you have any doubts, please post the configuration lines you are using to perform the redirection so we can review them.

Comment: @JotaMartos I updated the question with the config. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Niquify, did you modify the [ServerName directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername) of the default virtual host? It is configured in the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf file. If you set the ServerName parameter with the port there, that should be the cause of the wrong redirection.

Comment: @JotaMartos No I didn't. I also opened a thread on bitnami, I added the bnsupport code if you can take a look: https://community.bitnami.com/t/bad-request-error-when-enabling-ssl-and-http-redirection/62821